# Unable to load JNA native support library Elasticsearch 6.x

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, jna, mount, umask

I have installed Elasticsearch 6.x in my `Debian 7 (wheezy)`. I tried to start with `service elasticsearch start` but its give me an error message

```
root@debian:~# sudo -i service elasticsearch start
[FAIL] Starting Elasticsearch Server: failed!
```

I tried to look at the elasticsearch log files at `nano /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log`, and i got this error

```
[2017-12-14T11:25:39,153][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] unable to load JNA native support library, native methods will be disabled.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/linux-x86/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path ([file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-spatial-$
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:962) ~[jna-4.4.0-1.jar:4.4.0 (b0)]
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:922) ~[jna-4.4.0-1.jar:4.4.0 (b0)]
        at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:190) ~[jna-4.4.0-1.jar:4.4.0 (b0)]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Natives.<clinit>(Natives.java:45) [elasticsearch-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:103) [elasticsearch-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:171) [elasticsearch-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:322) [elasticsearch-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:121) [elasticsearch-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:112) [elasticsearch-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) [elasticsearch-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) [elasticsearch-cli-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-cli-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) [elasticsearch-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:85) [elasticsearch-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
[2017-12-14T11:25:39,212][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot check if running as root because JNA is not available
[2017-12-14T11:25:39,212][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot install system call filter because JNA is not available
[2017-12-14T11:25:39,215][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot register console handler because JNA is not available
[2017-12-14T11:25:39,256][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot getrlimit RLIMIT_NPROC because JNA is not available
[2017-12-14T11:25:39,256][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot getrlimit RLIMIT_AS beacuse JNA is not available
[2017-12-14T11:25:39,256][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot getrlimit RLIMIT_FSIZE because JNA is not available
```

How can i fixed this ? i have installed java, and it's `version javac 1.8.0_151`

what could go wrong with my code ?
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i have find the solution. Apparently my vm memory storage (RAM) was 1 GB - 2 GB, so i increase my VM's RAM capacity to at least 4GB and i reboot the machine. And elastic search started work just fine.

Answer (score 25):

1. Go to `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch`
2. Add `ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Djna.tmpdir=/var/lib/elasticsearch/tmp"`.

   (For newer Elasticsearch, use `Djava.io.tmpdir` instead of `Djna.tmpdir`)
3. Start Elasticsearch using `systemctl start elasticsearch` or `service start elasticsearch`.
4. You can see now `tmp` folder created inside `/var/lib/elasticsearch/`.
5. This folder should have execute permission for `elasticsearch` user
6. Check the permission with name `i -l /var/lib/elasticsearch`
7. Make sure the permission file have something like below permission

   ```
   dr-xr-xr-x root          root          /
   drwxr-xr-x root          root          var
   drwxr-xr-x root          root          lib
   drwxr-x--- elasticsearch elasticsearch elasticsearch
   ```

I hope your issue will be resolved.

Comment: seems I cant find this /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch, i see only /etc

Comment: Windows or linux machine?

Comment: Changing jvm heap size in /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options to -Xms2g (minimum heap size) and -Xmx2g (maximum heap size) and reloading daemon and restarting elasticsearch might help to resolve the issue as well. Change those values based up on your server resources.

Comment: For newer versions of the ElasitcSearch you should use "-Djava.io.tmpdir" Java variable instead of the "Djna.tmpdir". @deppfx stated this correct name of the variable below.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderReznikov for your input on this.

Comment: Yes this is the perfect fix.    I have also fixed using the same method on Centos 7   Cpanel /WHM

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-no-longer-works-under-systemd-7-4-0-on-centos-7-7-1908/201846/4

Comment: This worked great with ElasticSearch 7.9 as well, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @Jsilvermist

Comment: It could be `/etc/default/elasticsearch` for Debian OS's (like Ubuntu) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setting-system-settings.html

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue on a CentOS7 cPanel server with ElasticSearch 7.8 installed via YUM.
As per the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50371992/2828681), I did the following:

1. Set `ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Djna.tmpdir=/var/lib/elasticsearch/tmp"` in `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch`
2. `mkdir -p /var/lib/elasticsearch/tmp`
3. `chown -R elasticsearch.elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch/tmp`

Comment: this worked for me with the same setup as you (cpanel + centos 7). thank you so much!!

Comment: The guidance here is a couple of years out of date; since https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/80651 the right fix is described at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.12/executable-jna-tmpdir.html and says to set `ES_TMPDIR` instead of any system properties.

Answer (score 6):

Check the permissions on your `/tmp/` directory. It must have had `noexec`.

`/tmp` needs `exec` to support JNA. A workaround is to specify a `tmp` directory in elasticsearch sysconfig file.

Something like `export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=$ES_HOME/tmp"`

Make sure there is a `$ES_HOME/tmp` directory and `elasticsearch` user has write permissions to it.

I had this issue as I was using a hardened OS and also because the default umask is `0027`.

Comment: The guidance here is a couple of years out of date; since https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/80651 the right fix is described at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.12/executable-jna-tmpdir.html and says to set `ES_TMPDIR` instead of any system properties.

Answer (score 2):

The same problem happened to me on **Windows 10** when running from command prompt:

```
unable to load JNA native support library, native methods will be disabled.
```

To solve this, it was enough to run *elasticsearch.exe* with Admin rights *(Click Start -> type "Command" -> right click on "Command Prompt" -> select "Run as Administrator")*

Answer (score 1):

For me below worked:

```
PUT your_index_name/_settings
    {
    "index": {
    "blocks": {
    "read_only_allow_delete": "false"
    }
    }
    }
```

I followed below link:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/forbidden-12-index-read-only-allow-delete-api/110282/4

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04, the solution was

> sudo systemctl edit --full elasticsearch.service

adding a line

> Environment=ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/elasticsearch/tmp"

exitting with -x as in vi

restarting the service

> sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch.service

Comment: The guidance here is a couple of years out of date; since https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/80651 the right fix is described at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.12/executable-jna-tmpdir.html and says to set `ES_TMPDIR` instead of any system properties.