# Elasticsearch service failing when /tmp is mounted noexec

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jna

Elasticsearch service is failing when `/tmp` is mounted with `noexec`.  When I try to remount it with `exec`, the service is getting started.

Is the below link still valid or there is permanent solution or workaround?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/executable-jna-tmpdir.html

Q. I would like to know how can we change the path of Elasticsearch logs which its trying to write in /tmp? (something like '/var/' or '/opt' which is already mounted as exec)

Q. Also can you please tell, if this logs are temporary and elasticsearch service deletes it after some time ? if yes then only it make sense to change path to something like '/var' or '/opt'

Below are the logs.

1.

## **systemctl status elasticsearch.service**

```
elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.d
           └─startup-timeout.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-11-20 14:52:12 IST; 16min ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 48882 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 48882 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service

Nov 20 14:51:34 <HOSTNAME> systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Nov 20 14:51:38 <HOSTNAME> elasticsearch[48882]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will ...release.
Nov 20 14:52:12 <HOSTNAME> elasticsearch[48882]: ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
Nov 20 14:52:12 <HOSTNAME> elasticsearch[48882]: [1]: system call filters failed to install; check the logs and fix your configuration or disable sy...own risk
Nov 20 14:52:12 <HOSTNAME> systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 20 14:52:12 <HOSTNAME> systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
Nov 20 14:52:12 <HOSTNAME> systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
Nov 20 14:52:12 <HOSTNAME> systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service failed.
```

2. 

## **journalctl -fu elasticsearch**

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2020-11-17 13:09:05 IST. --
Nov 20 14:51:38 <HOSTNAME> elasticsearch[48882]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Nov 20 14:52:12 <HOSTNAME> elasticsearch[48882]: ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
Nov 20 14:52:12 <HOSTNAME> elasticsearch[48882]: [1]: system call filters failed to install; check the logs and fix your configuration or disable system call filters at your own risk
Nov 20 14:52:12 <HOSTNAME> systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 20 14:52:12 <HOSTNAME> systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
Nov 20 14:52:12 <HOSTNAME> systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
Nov 20 14:52:12 <HOSTNAME> systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service failed.
```

3. 

**/var/log/elasticsearch/<cluster-name.log>**

```
[2020-11-20T14:51:53,369][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] [elasticsearch_1] unable to load JNA native support library, native methods will be disabled.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/elasticsearch-9221628356394379624/jna--1985354563/jna10392232823311871934.tmp: /tmp/elasticsearch-9221628356394379624/jna--1985354563/jna10392232823311871934.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2440) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2497) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2627) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:744) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1870) ~[?:?]
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:947) ~[jna-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1 (b0)]
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:922) ~[jna-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1 (b0)]
        at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:190) ~[jna-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1 (b0)]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:333) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Natives.<clinit>(Natives.java:45) [elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:104) [elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:172) [elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:349) [elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) [elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) [elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) [elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:125) [elasticsearch-cli-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-cli-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115) [elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) [elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
[2020-11-20T14:51:53,380][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] [elasticsearch_1] cannot check if running as root because JNA is not available
[2020-11-20T14:51:53,380][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] [elasticsearch_1] cannot install system call filter because JNA is not available
[2020-11-20T14:51:53,381][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] [elasticsearch_1] cannot register console handler because JNA is not available
[2020-11-20T14:51:53,382][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] [elasticsearch_1] cannot getrlimit RLIMIT_NPROC because JNA is not available
[2020-11-20T14:51:53,382][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] [elasticsearch_1] cannot getrlimit RLIMIT_AS because JNA is not available
[2020-11-20T14:51:53,382][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] [elasticsearch_1] cannot getrlimit RLIMIT_FSIZE because JNA is not available
[2020-11-20T14:51:53,612][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [elasticsearch_1] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/opt (/dev/mapper/appvg-lv_opt)]], net usable_space [121.8gb], net total_space [147.5gb], types [ext4]
[2020-11-20T14:51:53,614][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [elasticsearch_1] heap size [5.1gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2020-11-20T14:51:53,617][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elasticsearch_1] node name [elasticsearch_1], node ID [6OyoyA40S3-z6M7nAnCGIA], cluster name [<cluster name>]
[2020-11-20T14:51:53,617][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elasticsearch_1] version[7.4.0], pid[48882], build[default/rpm/22e1767283e61a198cb4db791ea66e3f11ab9910/2019-09-27T08:36:48.569419Z], OS[Linux/3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64/amd64], JVM[AdoptOpenJDK/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/13/13+33]
[2020-11-20T14:51:53,618][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elasticsearch_1] JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk]
[2020-11-20T14:51:53,618][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elasticsearch_1] JVM arguments [-Xms5288m, -Xmx5288m, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-9221628356394379624, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/elasticsearch, -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -Xms5288m, -Xmx5288m, -Dio.netty.allocator.type=pooled, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2772434944, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=rpm, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]
[2020-11-20T14:51:55,967][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [elasticsearch_1] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2020-11-20T14:51:55,968][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [elasticsearch_1] loaded module [analysis-common]
org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.MonitoringService$MonitoringExecution$1.doRun(MonitoringService.java:242) [x-pack-monitoring-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:703) [elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) [?:?]
[2020-11-20T14:52:11,962][ERROR][o.e.x.m.c.c.StatsCollector] [elasticsearch_1] collector [ccr_stats] failed to collect data
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.collector.Collector.collect(Collector.java:85) [x-pack-monitoring-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.MonitoringService$MonitoringExecution$1.doRun(MonitoringService.java:242) [x-pack-monitoring-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:703) [elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) [?:?]
[2020-11-20T14:52:11,963][ERROR][o.e.x.m.c.i.IndexStatsCollector] [elasticsearch_1] collector [index-stats] failed to collect data
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.collector.Collector.collect(Collector.java:85) [x-pack-monitoring-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.MonitoringService$MonitoringExecution$1.doRun(MonitoringService.java:242) [x-pack-monitoring-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:703) [elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) [?:?]
[2020-11-20T14:52:12,114][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [elasticsearch_1] publish_address {<IP of localhost>:5300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:5300}
[2020-11-20T14:52:12,123][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [elasticsearch_1] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2020-11-20T14:52:12,128][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [elasticsearch_1] node validation exception
[1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: system call filters failed to install; check the logs and fix your configuration or disable system call filters at your own risk
[2020-11-20T14:52:12,132][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elasticsearch_1] stopping ...
[2020-11-20T14:52:12,155][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elasticsearch_1] stopped
[2020-11-20T14:52:12,156][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elasticsearch_1] closing ...
[2020-11-20T14:52:12,166][ERROR][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [elasticsearch_1] fatal error in thread [Thread-3], exiting
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native
        at org.elasticsearch.systemd.Libsystemd.lambda$static$0(Libsystemd.java:34) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.systemd.Libsystemd.<clinit>(Libsystemd.java:33) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.systemd.SystemdPlugin.sd_notify(SystemdPlugin.java:66) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.systemd.SystemdPlugin.close(SystemdPlugin.java:87) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.core.internal.io.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:104) ~[elasticsearch-core-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.core.internal.io.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-core-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.close(Node.java:881) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.core.internal.io.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:104) ~[elasticsearch-core-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.core.internal.io.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:62) ~[elasticsearch-core-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$4.run(Bootstrap.java:186) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Your stack trace points to the root of the problem:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/elasticsearch-9221628356394379624/jna--1985354563/jna10392232823311871934.tmp: /tmp/elasticsearch-9221628356394379624/jna--1985354563/jna10392232823311871934.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted

The [link you provided](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/executable-jna-tmpdir.html) is accurate in describing the problem: JNA extracts its own native library stub to a temporary directory on your machine in order to work.  When the `/tmp` directory does not have the correct permissions for this library, you can't use it.  You can [see the loading code here](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/src/com/sun/jna/Native.java#L1277)

Regarding your question, yes, it is possible to extract that library elsewhere.  One simple solution is to extract the approprate `jnidispatch` library for your system yourself.

You can set any location and set `jna.boot.library.path` or use the system path and set `jna.nosys=false`.  See the [javadoc for the `Native` class](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.6.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html):

> When JNA classes are loaded, the native shared library (jnidispatch) is loaded as well. An attempt is made to load it from the any paths defined in jna.boot.library.path (if defined), then the system library path using System.loadLibrary(java.lang.String), unless jna.nosys=true. If not found, the appropriate library will be extracted from the class path (into a temporary directory if found within a jar file) and loaded from there, unless jna.noclasspath=true. If your system has additional security constraints regarding execution or load of files (SELinux, for example), you should probably install the native library in an accessible location and configure your system accordingly, rather than relying on JNA to extract the library from its own jar file.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you. I am not a developer so i didn't understand where exactly I need to set for different path. Can you please tell me in which file I need to set and what variable ? Thanks,

Comment: @pratkul007 If you have Java code you can use `System.setProperty("jna.boot.library.path", "\foo\bar")` to the location of the dll.  If you can control the command line switches, you can add `-Djna.boot.library.path=\foo\bar` to the command line string.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370545/how-do-i-make-a-target-library-available-to-my-java-app)

Comment: @pratkul007 It looks like with Elasticsearch you use `-E` rather than the `-D` for Java.  [See here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/auditbeat/current/using-environ-vars.html)

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for finding for me. just thinking In which file I need to add this variable in Elasticsearch config.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you. I found below link. I will try and let you know. THANKS.       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824643/unable-to-load-jna-native-support-library-elasticsearch-6-x